# How to use htaccess to serve cache .html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /cache/$1-$2.html
RewriteRule !((.txt)|(.xml)|(.json)|(.html)|(.js)|(.mp4)|images|uploads\/(.*)|cache\/(.*)|resources\/(.*)|control\/(.*)|fonts\/(.*)|offline\/(.*)|stylesheets\/(.*)|libs\/(.*)|javascripts\/(.*))$ index.php [NC]
```

This is my htaccess file.
It should be serving my cache files of /cache folder.

The problem I'm facing is:
I have a url like **site.com.br/blog/example-post/**
But I am saving this cache as **blog-example-post.html**

Also, if no cache file found, then open index.php to control all requests.
But, using cache I will decrease my server and DB requests.

Can someone please help me to **replace all / from requests to - in htaccess**?

**Edit: a possible solution for site.com.br/blog/my-post/amp/ (saved as: blog-my-post-amp.html**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2-$3.html [L]
```

Update: How it is working to me now

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2-$3.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2-$3.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2-$3-$4.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2-$3-$4.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1.xml -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1.xml [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2.xml -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2.xml [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2-$3.xml -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2-$3.xml [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2-$3-$4.xml -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2-$3-$4.xml [L]
```

I must fix somethings and maybe optimze the code. I will update here when it reach 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2.html -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*) /cache/$1-$2.html
> ```

The obvious issue here is you have two backreferences but only one capturing subpattern. `$2` is therefore always empty. If you are expecting a request of the form `/blog/example-post/`, which should map to a cache file `/cache/blog-example-post.html` then the rule should look more like this:

```
 :
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2.html [L]
```

Don't forget the `L` flag.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Edit: a possible solution for `example.com/blog/my-post/amp/` (saved as: `blog-my-post-amp.html`)
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2.html -f
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2.html [NC,L]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2-$3.html [L]
> ```

The `RewriteCond` (*condition*) only applies to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows (together they form one rule). So, the second `RewriteRule` rewrites the request unconditionally, regardless of whether the cached file exists or not.

You need to repeat the *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1-$2-$3.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /cache/$1-$2-$3.html [L]
```

*Aside:* The `NC` (`nocase`) flag on the first rule is superfluous since the regex `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$` is naturally case-insensitive anyway.

Comment: Works like a charm but if I try to access site.com.br/blog/example-post/amp/ it doesnt. I tried to add $3 in htaccess but it doesnt work

Comment: Edited main post with a possible solution but I dont know if this is the best one

Comment: @Lucas You need to include a _condition_ that checks whether the cached file exists. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I must fix somethings. I will do my best